# How to skip test Nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I use nightwatch.js, mocha.js and selenium web driver for acceptance testing for now.
And I need to skip some tests, how I can do it?

```
module.exports = {

"User logs in the WebPortal": function(browser) {
browser
  .url(urlAdress)
  .setValue('input#login', user.login)
  .setValue('input#password', user.password)
  .click('button.ui-button')
  .waitForElementPresent('a[href="/logout"]', middleTimer)
  .getText('a[href="/logout"] span', function(result) {
    (result.value).should.be.exactly("logout")
  })
  .end()
},
"User logs out": function(browser) {
browser
  .url(urlAdress)
  .setValue('input#login', user.login)
  .setValue('input#password', user.password)
  .click('button.ui-button')
  .waitForElementPresent('a[href="/logout"]', middleTimer)
  .click('a[href="/logout"]')
  .waitForElementPresent('button.ui-button', middleTimer)
  .getText('button.ui-button', function(result) {
    (result.value).should.be.exactly("Login")
  })
  .end()
}
}
```

So, how to skip one or more tests?
Thank you for answers.

Comment: Do you want to skip a test using command line parameters, or by adding some code to the test case?

Comment: @Jens Wegar, thank you, but I found the solution by adding mocha.js wrapper to my tests!

Comment: Cool! Would be good if you can add your solution as an answer to this question and accept it, so it gets removed from the list of unanswered questions ;)

Answer (score 12):

Without using `Mocha` or `Grunt`. I am able to skip using:

1. Use `'@disabled': true,` like this

   ```
   after module.exports = {
      '@disabled': true,
   ```

   it will will skip everything inside `module.exports = {`

   and print skip statement in console
2. Skip specific tests:

   In your `.js` file if you have so many tests and you want to skip specific test,
   use `''+` as prefix before test `function` in your test, like this:

   ```
   'Test 1': '' + function (client) {
    },
   'Test 2': '' + function (client) {
    },
   'Test 3': function (client) {
    }
   ```

   first two tests will be skipped and third will get executed. No skip statement will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

You can just prefix function keyword with exclamation `!` or some other valid character:

```
"User logs in the WebPortal": !function(browser) {
  browser
  .url(urlAdress)
  ...
  .end()
},
```

Tests marked by this way will not executed.